# How to fix piechart overlap centertext in MPAndroid Chart

Tags: android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

[image]

I don't know how to fix this problem.

```
pieChart.setHoleRadius(90);
pieChart.setCenterTextSize(18);
pieChart.setCenterText(getResouces().getString(R.string.test)+"\n\n"+minStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the text size using :

```
mData.setValueTextSize(16f);
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can choose one of these solutions:

- Shrink the font size.
- Put "\n\n" before your text. `pieChart.setCenterText("\n"+getResouces().getString(R.string.test)+"\n\n"+minStr);`
- Change the text to something shorter.